# Placing a range of text in a footer on a chart sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have text in cells N27:N30 and I would like that text to be copied into a footer on my chart sheet. Would anyone know if and how this can be done? I'm not familiar with how footers are created using VBA...Thank you

Comment: Figure out what you want to do and then do it with the macro recorder turned on. Don't use the resulting code directly -- but see what part of the Excel Object Model is used in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this.

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveChart.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""

'These lines are where you use data from the worksheet for you footer values
    .LeftFooter = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ChartSheet").Range("N27").Value
    .CenterFooter = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ChartSheet").Range("N28").Value & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ChartSheet").Range("N29").Value
    .RightFooter = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ChartSheet").Range("N30").Value

    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .ChartSize = xlScreenSize
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 100
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for the guidance!